# finite recursive "List" type

Tags: list, haskell, infinite

It is easy to reconstruct the list type in Haskell:

```
data MyList a = Cons a (MyList a)
               | Empty
               deriving (Show)

someList = Cons 1 (Cons 2 (Cons 3 Empty)) -- represents [1,2,3]
```

This allows for constructing infinites lists. Is it possible to somehow define a list type, that only allows for *finite* (but still arbitrary length) lists?

The example of lists here can replaced with any other potentially infinite data structures like trees etc. Note that I do not have any particular application in mind, so there is no need to question the usefullness of this, I'm just curious whether that would be possible.

Comment: Maybe this is something to look at https://hackage.haskell.org/package/fixed-list-0.1.6/docs/Data-FixedList.html

Comment: Haskell doesn't feature a termination checker, so you can't distinguish a computation which runs for ever from one which terminates. All recursive data structures are potentially infinite. Total languages (eg Agda, Coq) often distinguish _inductive_ (finite) datatypes from _coinductive_ (possibly-infinite) datatypes, but Haskell is not a total language.

Comment: This definitely doesn't answer the question, but doing the exact opposite is quite a bit easier! This: `data Stream a = Cons a (Stream a)` cannot have finite lists (excluding things like `undefined`).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### Alternative 1: lists with a strict tail

```
data MyList a = Cons a !(MyList a) | Empty
```

Trying to build an infinite list will surely lead to a bottom element of `MyList a`.

### Alternative 2: existentially-quantified fixed-length list

```
data Nat = O | S Nat
data List a (n :: Nat) where
   Nil :: List a O
   Cons :: a -> List a n -> List a (S n)
data MyList a where
   MyList :: List a n -> MyList a
```

I would say that this does not allow for infinite lists as well.

This is because we can't pattern match on a GADT with `where` (or lazy patterns in general).

```
-- fails to compile
test :: MyList Int
test = MyList (Cons 1 list)
       where MyList list = test
```

The following would be too strict.

```
-- diverges
test2 :: MyList Int
test2 = case test2 of
          MyList list -> MyList (Cons 1 list)
```

The following makes the existentially quantified type variable "escape" the scope of the `case`:

```
-- fails to compile
test3 :: MyList Int
test3 = MyList $ case test3 of
          MyList list -> (Cons 1 list)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for these examples! I was not aware of the strict fields. I'm trying to understand alternative 2 now: It seems that `Nat` basically implements the natural numbers. I don't quite understand the last two lines (`data MyList a where ...`),  what is going on there?

Comment: @flawr it's a [Generalised Algebraic DataType](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Haskell/GADT), in this case used to _existentially_ encapsulate a type variable (namely, the type encoded length `n`). So, basically this packs a type-level number into a runtime value.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation and link, I'll probably have to look into that when I'm a little bit more familiar with Haskell!

Comment: Haskell types must be finite, which gives you a shortcut for proving the finiteness of all values in Alternative 2.

Comment: @flawr Yes, that would be advisable. Haskell type-level machinery is quite advanced, and some of its most powerful features, like GADTs + DataKinds + etc. can be a bit intimidating at first. It's indeed better to become familiar with the basic algebraic data types, and the rest of Haskell, first.

Comment: @rampion Probably that's enough, yes. Still, 1) type are erased at runtime,  2) the concrete values for the existentially quantified `n::Nat` are not known at compile time, 3) `n` would be known at runtime if it weren't erased. This makes me a little unconfortable, but I'm probably paranoic here. I just need to convince myself that types `n` could be kept at runtime, and that erasure is only an optimization.

Comment: Consider `MyList (fix (Cons 1))`.  Even though the type of `fix (Cons 1)` is erased at runtime, it still must have *some* legal type, which is why the compiler complains `Occurs check: cannot construct the infinite type: n0 ~ 'S n0`.

Comment: Can't the first result in a *circular list*? Like `let x = Cons 1 x`?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem That will diverge, it is equivalent to `let x = seq x (Cons 1 x)`, or to `let x=x`.